# How to solve to one variable of the functions, giving the others first (Fsolve)

Tags: python, solver

I have been trying to find a way to solve to one variable of the fucntion using the other one as a known. for examplpe.

```
def f(x,y):

    return x+y

sol=scipy.optimize.fsolve(f(x,1),0)
```

which is obviously wrong, but you get the idea. return that x=-1.

It's rather simple but have not find this in google or on documentation

Comment: The code is not complete or correct enough. What is the `fsolve` function? Please indent your code also.

Comment: Didn't know how to do it. Im sry! Also added the function :) @andreihondrari

Comment: x+y is a linear equation always so I don't know why you are trying to use a nonlinear function solver to solve it

Comment: for any x+y=0 if x is given there is always only 1 y that completes your equation, if your true equation is nonlinear, you should consider posting your real equation and then attempt to fsolve it because fsolve is not designed for linear equations which is why this is failing.

Comment: @d_kennetz this is a simple example used to convey the problem, the fact that the equation given is linear has nothing to do with why the problem is challenging.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can look at [sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html?highlight=solve#module-sympy.solvers).

```
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import Symbol
x = Symbol('x')
y = Symbol('y')
solve(x+y, x, y)
# [(−y,y)]
solve(x+y, x, 1)
# [(−y,1)]
```

It does not return the answer in the exact way you expect, but I think you can interpret it to generate the outcome you want.

Comment: this does  not return the solution tho. Also the equation I want to solve is super complex and have to pass many arguements.

Comment: @BillyMatlock I recommend you to follow the link I've posted to read up on the different kinds of solvers that `sympy` package provides. `sympy` is an established algebraic solver package for Python and I am sure you would be able to find functions that can suit your purpose there.

Answer (score 0):

How about defining the function inside another function and passing that to fsolve, like so:

```
from scipy import optimize
def createFunc(y):
    def optimisedFunc(x):
        return x+y
    return optimisedFunc

sol=scipy.optimize.fsolve(createFunc(1),0)
print(sol)

>>> array([-1.])
```

Let me know if anything is unclear and I can clarify it, defining functions within functions is a strange thing to think about.